# Image readystate in canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, loading, drawimage, loaded

Is it possible to use imagename.readyState in canvas?

If not does anyone know a way of detecting when an image being drawn to the canvas using "drawImage" has loaded and is ready to display?

I am creating an image showcase using the canvas - when an image is selected I want to have a loading animation (which I have already created) display until the loaded condition is met.

I am still learning to use javascript and have been trying all day to no avail - so apologies for the lack of example code to display and illustrate what I'm asking!

Answer (score 2):

You might try loading the image by using `new Image()` and setting the `.onload` event to draw the image on the canvas after the image has been loaded.

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
    // code to draw image on the canvas...
}
img.src = "/path/to/img.jpg";
```

See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/canvas-tutorial/3_1_canvas_drawimage.html

Comment: Are there other ways of detecting?  I tried using this but for what I'm trying to do I had no joy - I need to be able to detect when the image is loading (or unloaded).